# What could be the cause for error 1001 when installing my C# .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net

I faced an error 1001 when I was trying to test installing the new version of my Windows application:

```
Error 1001 . An Exception occurred during the commit phase of the installation. This exception will        
be ignored and installation will continue. However , the application might not function correctly 
after installation is complete --> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler, 
Version=1.8.3.15820,Culture=neutural,PublicKeyToke...
```

This error only occurs when an old version of this application is in system. If I delete the old version, this installation will run fine.

I just took over this project and I am new to C# .Net. I really have no clue what happened. I searched and I only found someone got this error when he was installing windows services.

What could possibly cause this problem? Can anyone point out a direction for me to follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is very obvious from that error that a library file is missing named : `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll` has to be deployed / packed with the installer which can be downloaded from : [Here](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. But the installation runs fine if system is clean. The issue occurs only when there is an old version of this application in system. How is that possible?